# Jquery $.get loop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

A Jquery mobile / JavaScript problem

I am unable to get this "get" to correctly loop trough the various values of data, where it should send

...cmd=PC&data=06464ff

...cmd=PC&data=16464ff

...cmd=PC&data=26464ff

```
i = 0;
do {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $.get('send.php', {
            ip: ip,
            id: id,
            port: port,
            cmd: "PC",
            data: i + "6464ff"
        }).done(function (response) {
            if (response.indexOf("PC") === 0) {
                response = response.replace("PC", "");
            } else {
                $("#ERROR").html(response);
                response = currentvm;
            }
        });
    }, 2000 * i);
    i++;
}
while (i < 255);
```

all I get is

...cmd=PC&data=2556464ff

...cmd=PC&data=2556464ff

Any thoughts or suggestions as to how do proceed.

Thank you.

Comment: so... what's the error?

Comment: your logic is failing, you could use a closure

Comment: So basically you want to make an ajax call every two seconds for the next nine hours. Seems like a great idea ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AJAX call in for loop won't return values to correct array positions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405064/ajax-call-in-for-loop-wont-return-values-to-correct-array-positions)

Comment: ok, its not actually going to be 2000, but 2 second is a good time for me to see what is going out, cynicism, really

Comment: I am very new to JavaScript so I was not 100% sure what to search for in here, I do apologies for creating a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a closure should fix your issue:

```
do {
    (function (i) {
        setTimeout(function () {

            $.get('send.php', {
                ip: ip,
                id: id,
                port: port,
                cmd: "PC",
                data: i + "6464ff"
            }).done(function (response) {
                if (response.indexOf("PC") === 0) {
                    response = response.replace("PC", "");
                } else {
                    $("#ERROR").html(response);
                    response = currentvm;
                }
            });
        }, 2000 * i);
    }(i));
    i++;
}
while (i < 255);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, had a little hiccup were I forgot to declare I, oops.

Answer (score -1):

Possible options:
try changing 'send.php' by 'send.php?'+i+ "6464ff"

or

```
$.get('send.php', {
    ip: ip,
    id: id,
    port: port,
    cmd: "PC",
    data: i + "6464ff",
    success: function(response) {
    if (response.indexOf("PC") === 0) {
        response = response.replace("PC", "");
    }
    else {$("#ERROR").html(response);
        response = currentvm;
    }
});
```