# ajax in a for loop won't return a correct values in array position, despite closure binds scope of current value position

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, closures

This question may be a duplicate of [[AJAX call in for loop won't return values to correct array positions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2405064/305883]) - I am applying the [answer of Plynx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2405188/305883).

**My problem is that the closure will not go through all the element in a loop**. Yet, the browser's network show all ajax calls have been successful.

The ajax will return data mis-matched from the current element passed on the closure.

---

I have an array of IDs *items*; the current ID is given by the `i`-th position in a loop; an ajax call should process the current ID in the loop and return data like:

```
data[id] = {object}
```

Since the closure is skipping some `i` element of the loop, the current id (`items[i]`) fed to the closure is mis-matched from the returned data.

```
// ajax function test: it returns "data[key] = ..", where key === id
function fetchDecorator (id) {

  var loadurl = 'http://localhost/';

    return $.ajax({
    url: loadurl,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: true,
    async: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
       id: id
     },
    jsonpCallback: 'onFetchComplete'

  });

};

// callback function for ajax response
function onFetchComplete(data) {
  console.log('is data fetched?', data);
  return data
}

//items is an array of numeric ids: [7955,943987,4834331,..]
    for (var i = items.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        (function (i){
            var currentID = items[i];
// first test
            console.log('current i',i,'current id', currentID);

            fetchDecorator(items[i])
            .done(function(data){
// second test
                console.log('current i',i ,',current ID in items[i] is', items[i], 'actual ID is:', Object.keys(data));
            })
        })(i);

    };
```

Results from tests:

(1) All the `i`-th element are being processed:

```
current i 209 , current id 24159975
current i 208 , current id 30833420
current i 207 , current id 14778161
current i 206 , current id 5798582
...
```

Could you help in figuring out why the closure does not process all the elements?

(2) Some `i`-th elements are skipped in the closure: (here, 208,207,205,204 are missing); returned actual ID are different from current ID:

```
current i 209, current ID in items[i] is 24159975, actual ID is: ["14778161"]
current i 206, current ID in items[i] is 5798582, actual ID is: ["5798582"]
current i 203, current ID in items[i] is 37369491, actual ID is: ["27962727"] ...
```

I need to ensure the closure will process all elements and return data matching the current `i` position.

Comment: Sounds like an issue server side, not sure what returns your requests

Comment: `console.log` output in your code doesn't match with your output: `console.log('current i',i ,'current ID in items[i]', items[i], 'act...` vs `current i 203, current ID in items[i] is 37369491, act...`

Comment: Hi @a-wolff I don't think is server side cause in the console of browser I can see ajax are actually done. Though the console.log() does not return all the i-th elements - it looks like an asyn problem for being the i-th counter going on while the ajax function being executed, but I thought that with the closure I should I have solved. Is there maybe smetg I m missing?

Comment: @mostruash what is mismatching? did you find my question unclear?

Comment: @user305883 The string you log doesn't have the word `is` yet it is there in the output that you say you see. You don't print `currentID` at all.

Comment: ..k edited, I do print currentID, see // first.test and result in console.log() 1).

Answer (score 0):

So both `currentID` and `items[i]` have correct ids, but data you receive from ajax call has them wrong:

```
current i 209 , current id 24159975
...
current i 209, current ID in items[i] is 24159975, actual ID is: ["14778161"]
```

As you can see, `data` has wrong data. It definitely is not a problem with closures.

And the reason some items are skipped is because `done` callback is not called for some of them, i.e. some ajax calls actually fail.

Comment: Ajax calls are done for all the elements, I can see them in browers's network resources. As example, I fetch data from wikipedia: data structure is `data.query.pages[key]` where `key` is the `id` and should be equal to the current ID in my `items` array. I cannot figure out why, in the first test (no ajax), the loop goes through all element; in the second one (with ajax), it does not. I thought the mis-match between the i-th element (current id) and the actual id of the page, is due to `actual id` being processed while counter of i element is increasing. But not clear why it happen.

Comment: As I told you already, requests are made but some of them fail or do not complete (check request results from browser and compare, they must be all 2xx, eg 200). Thats why some closures (done callbacks) are skipped.

Comment: This is what I get as example: when closure processes a first element of my array, say `items[209]`, the ajax-fetched `actual ID` matches the `current id`. Then the closure skips some elements. The second `current id` being processed is some positions afterwards in my array - say, `items[200]`; here the `actual id` fetched corresponds to `id` in a further position in my array: e.g. items[198]. It looks like that counter goes ahead while closure is being done: `Actual Id`  <= to the `id` of the current position in array `items[i]` being passed on.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution by avoiding to pass on the ajax object to 
`done()` function, and use a `callback` instead.

Conceptually, I did not figure out why the previous code would give error: I will be happy if you can help to spot the difference.

@monstruash raised the possibility that some ajax call, in the previous code, may have failed. 
I also let jquery handle the callback by itself here: `jsonp = callback`
[http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/](jquery documentation on ajax)

This is what I've done:

```
function fetchDecorator (id, callback) {

var loadurl = 'http://localhost/';

return $.ajax({
url: loadurl,
type: 'GET',
cache: true,
async: true,
dataType: 'jsonp',
data: {
   id: id
 },
jsonp: 'callback',
success: callback

});
};


// then, for each element, do something
// here I used a map() function, but you could use a loop too
// 'items' is an array of ids.

$.map(items, function( id, position ) {
                fetchDecorator(id, function(data){
                    console.log(id, items[position], data.query.pages);
                    // do something

                })

            });
```